# How to use Count for specific condition

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

How Can I count and show how many Opportunity have Stage 3 but dont have Stage 2?

```
+-------+-------+
| OppID | Stage |
+-------+-------+
| ABC   |     1 |
| ABC   |     2 |
| ABC   |     3 |
| ABC   |     4 |
| CDF   |     3 |
| CDF   |     4 |
| EFG   |     1 |
| EFG   |     2 |
| EFG   |     3 |
| HIJ   |     2 |
| HIJ   |     3 |
| LMI   |     1 |
| LMI   |     2 |
| LMI   |     4 |
+-------+-------+
```

The count result is 1

```
+-------+-------+
| OppID | Stage |
+-------+-------+
| CDF   |     3 |
| CDF   |     4 |
+-------+-------+
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: What is desired output? Provide more info and show us what you have tried.

Comment: Use **Where** clause, If Stage 4 occurs only after stage 3 then `SELECT COUNT(*) from table_name where Stage>=3` Else if only Stage 3 is required then `SELECT COUNT(*) from table_name where Stage=3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, you could use `NOT EXISTS` and `COUNT DISTINCT` in following:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT OppID) 
FROM tbl AS t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl AS t2 WHERE t1.OppID = t2.OppID and t2.Stage = 2) and t1.Stage = 3
```

Comment: Count that have stage 3 but dont have stage 2. The count should give 1